# countif range based on cell value in another sheet vba

Tags: excel, vba

i have multisheets with on workbook the name of sheets as today date, my question (how i can countif range based on specific range in another sheets)

the range will search in multisheets (X4:X16) i want to count the value in this range if repeat more than 1 and paste the result in master sheet(Main of Month) range (AB3:AB16)

any help for, thanks

```
Function MyCOUNTIF(ByVal userRange As Variant, ByVal userCriteria As Variant)
     MyCOUNTIF = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.range("X4:X16",Sheets("MainofMonth".range("AB3:AB")))
End Function
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Miles Fett, thanks For your reply try with different code not work with i want, now i try with this function but failure try (Function MyCOUNTIF(ByVal userRange As Variant, ByVal userCriteria As Variant)
    MyCOUNTIF = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.range ("X4:X16", Sheets("Main of Month".range("AB3:AB")))
End Function
)

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you creating a COUNTIF function when one already exists in Excel?

Comment: zack thanks for reply, I don't no how used counting formula inside macro that why creating function, function not work with me, I try to creating macro